# IOS: Invalid `Podfile` file: no implicit conversion of nil into String

Tags: ios, react-native, npm, npx, pod-install

I just started learning react-native. While trying to run `npx pod-install` I get:

```
Scanning for pods...
1.11.3
> pod install
Auto-linking React Native modules for target `AudioOnlyRN`: RNCAsyncStorage, RNCClipboard, react-native-background-timer, react-native-daily-js, and react-native-webrtc
[Codegen] Generating ./build/generated/ios/React-Codegen.podspec.json

[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: no implicit conversion of nil into String.

 #  from /.../react-native/ios/Podfile:9
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #
 >    use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])
 #
 #  -------------------------------------------
Couldn't install Pods. Updating the Pods project and trying again...
> pod install --repo-update
Auto-linking React Native modules for target `AudioOnlyRN`: RNCAsyncStorage, RNCClipboard, react-native-background-timer, react-native-daily-js, and react-native-webrtc
[Codegen] Generating ./build/generated/ios/React-Codegen.podspec.json

[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: no implicit conversion of nil into String.

 #  from /.../react-native/ios/Podfile:9
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #
 >    use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])
 #
 #  -------------------------------------------
Couldn't install Pods. Updating the Pods project and trying again...
Command `pod install` failed.
└─ Cause: Invalid `Podfile` file: no implicit conversion of nil into String.

 #  from /.../react-native/ios/Podfile:9
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #
 >    use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])
 #
 #  -------------------------------------------
```

Any idea what mismatch do I have going on here?

I'm not sure I understand the hierarchy of the relationships between node_modules/package.json and Podfile.

Answer (score 61):

try changing

```
use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])
                                  ^               ^
```

to

```
use_react_native!(:path => config[:reactNativePath])
                                  ^
```

Comment: not working for me

Comment: I already have that 
use_react_native!(:path => config[:reactNativePath],
but still getting the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a very similar (albeit different) error:

```
[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: no implicit conversion of Pathname into String.
```

For me the issue was that react-native was set as a peer dependency. When I added react-native as a regular dependency, the pod install worked without error.